# How to write a query in method syntax

Tags: c#, .net, linq

If there is an `ObservableCollection` of class `Printer` called `Printers`...
and each `Printer` contains properties `IsSelected` (bool) and `Index` (int)...
how can I transform the following LINQ query from query syntax to method syntax?

```
string[] printerListing = 
    (from p in Printers
    where p.IsSelected
    select p.Index.ToString()).ToArray();
```

I came up with the following, but it only returns the first `Printer` from the query (split across multiple lines for readability):

```
var printers2 =
    Printers.Where(p => p.IsSelected)
    .FirstOrDefault()
    .Index.ToString().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] printerListing = 
    (from p in Printers
     where p.IsSelected
     select p.Index.ToString()).ToArray();
```

You can do this simply step by step from the end of your query to the beginning:

1. `ToArray();` stays:

   ```
   ....ToArray();
   ```
2. `select`:

   ```
   ....Select(p => p.Index.ToString()).ToArray();
   ```
3. `where`:

   ```
   ....Where(p => p.IsSelected).Select(p => p.Index.ToString()).ToArray();
   ```
4. `from` (the source):

   ```
   Printers.Where(p => p.IsSelected).Select(p => p.Index.ToString()).ToArray();
   ```

So finally:

```
string[] printerListing = 
               Printers
                   .Where(p => p.IsSelected)
                   .Select(p => p.Index.ToString())
                   .ToArray();
```

---

Actually, it's also working the other way round, but sometimes the reverse order is easier to follow.

Comment: Plus one for leading me through this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use [.Select()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx), which functions like the `select` keyword in query syntax.

```
var printers2 = Printers
                    .Where(p => p.IsSelected)
                    .Select(x => x.Index.ToString())
                    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `FirstOrDefault()` so it will return one first element where isSelected = true.
Use

```
var printers2 = Printers.Where(p => p.IsSelected)
                        .Select(x => x.Index.ToString).ToArray();
```